# Excel =CELL("color",[Cell]) Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I guess I'm a little confused by the `CELL` function within Excel. I'm using Excel 2010 and decided to try to figure out the [CELL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf) as it pertains to the cells color. The documentation reads: *The value 1 if the cell is formatted in color for negative values; otherwise returns 0 (zero).* However, the image below is what has me confused.

[image: Cell Formatting]

The content in the C column are the formulas, and the content in the D column are the results from the formulas. I have tried so many different formatting options (including Conditional Formatting) on this simple test, but cannot get the value of `=CELL("color",B1)` to be anything but `0`.

Any information on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Documentation says:

> The value 1 if the cell is formatted in color for negative values;
>   otherwise returns 0 (zero).

An example of a format that would generate a "1": Right click a cell -> Format Cells -> Select Number -> Choose the second format where the negative number appears in red.

Comment: My goodness that is the most simplistic answer for a totally non-simplistic set of documentation. Thank you, I can sleep at night now.